# How do you create a host-only network in Vagrant for NFS?

Tags: networking, vagrant

I cannot find any information in the docs about this error message:

```
NFS requires a host-only network to be created.
Please add a host-only network to the machine (with either DHCP or a
static IP) for NFS to work.
```

Here is my Vagrant config:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config| 
 config.vm.box = "localbox" 
 config.vm.network "public_network", hostonly: "192.168.33.10"
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www",  
    :nfs => true, 
    :mount_options =>['noacl,nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,nodiratime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768']
```

When asked, I pick my Airport connection for the bridge (Wi-Fi (AirPort)).

I cannot find a single usage of `hostonly` in the Vagrant docs.

Using Vagrant 1.7.4

My goal is simply to be able to access the VM running on one computer in my house, from other computers (and my phone) in my house.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have NFS and Public/bridge network try this:

*Vagrantfile*

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.100"
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.20.200"
```

or

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.100"
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.20.200", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `hostonly` by `ip` in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```